# How do I resize an image gif I placed on the background of a CSS div

Tags: css

```css
    #box-2
    {
      width:50%;
      height:80%;
      background-color: rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.116);
      border:transparent;
      background-image:url(human.gif);
  
    }
```

b

```css
#box-2
{
    width:50%;
    height:80%;
    background-color: rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.116);
    border:transparent;
    background-image:url(human.gif);
  
}
```

```html
  <div 
          id="box-2">
             <p class="display-6">Information</p>
    
             <h6 style="text-align: center;">How to nagivate through the Map</h6>
    
            
             <div class="foo blue"></div><ul>Lecture halls</ul>
             <div class="foo orange"></div><ul>Eating Places</ul>
             <div class="foo purple"></div><ul>Residences</ul>
             <div class="foo black"></div><ul>School Services</ul>
             <div class="foo green"></div><ul>Schools</ul>
          
          </div>
```

I would like to know how to resize the gif I placed on my div, I only added the gif on the CSS background and not on the HTML code

Comment: `background-size` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css property `background-size`. For example, if you want the image to cover the box, you coose `cover`. You can also enter fixed values.
See here for more Information: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

```css
#box-2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.116);
  border: transparent;
  background-image: url(human.gif);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-2">
  <p class="display-6">Information</p>

  <h6 style="text-align: center;">How to nagivate through the Map</h6>


  <div class="foo blue"></div>
  <ul>Lecture halls</ul>
  <div class="foo orange"></div>
  <ul>Eating Places</ul>
  <div class="foo purple"></div>
  <ul>Residences</ul>
  <div class="foo black"></div>
  <ul>School Services</ul>
  <div class="foo green"></div>
  <ul>Schools</ul>

</div>
```